# I accidentally put my computer to sleep during ubuntu dist-upgrade. How do I resume the update?

Tags: updates, update-manager

My computer was in the process of updating from Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10

Durring this, I accidentally put my computer to sleep. When I open my computer now, I see the lockscreen. However, when I click my account and enter my credentials, it takes me back to the account selection screen.

My update was started by running "sudo apt dist-upgrade" from the terminal. Is my update still continuing while on the login screen? I just want my update to finish without any corruptions.

I can log into a tty session. Is there any way I can use this to check the status of the update and if it's still running?

Comment: you can see it still running with `sudo ps aux | grep dist`, if you find a match, you can try bringing it back to foreground [following this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45029/290307). Another option if it's stuck, is to kill it using the PID, and start over in the tty. Last option is do a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, if it says that the apt is locked, you can try one of the above suggestions.

Comment: Using `dist-upgrade` to do a *release upgrade* is fully supported in Debian, but is not supported in Ubuntu. It might work, it might not...but you're pretty much on your own.